# jQuery $.ajax request of dataType json will not retrieve data from PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been looking all over for the solution but I cannot find anything that works.
I am trying to get a bunch of data from the database and then via AJAX autocomplete input fields in a form. To do this I've decided to use json, because why not, right? Alternatively I've been thinking to just send back a delimited string and then tokenise it, which in hind-sight would've been much easier and spared me the headache... Since I've decided to use json though, I guess I should stick with it and find out what went wrong! 
What happens is that when the get_member_function() is executed, an error pops up in an alert dialogue and reads "[object Object]". I've tried this also using the GET request, and by setting the contentType to ”application/json; charset=utf-8″. Alas, no dice. Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong? Take care, Piotr.

My javascript/jQuery function is as follows:

```
function get_member_info()
   {

   var url = "contents/php_scripts/admin_scripts.php"; 
   var id = $( "select[ name = member ] option:selected" ).val();

   $.ajax(
   {

      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,
      data: { get_member: id },
      success: function( response ) 
      { 

          $( "input[ name = type ]:eq( " + response.type + " )" ).attr( "checked", "checked" );
          $( "input[ name = name ]" ).val( response.name );
          $( "input[ name = fname ]" ).val( response.fname );
          $( "input[ name = lname ]" ).val( response.lname );
          $( "input[ name = email ]" ).val( response.email );
          $( "input[ name = phone ]" ).val( response.phone );
          $( "input[ name = website ]" ).val( response.website );
          $( "#admin_member_img" ).attr( "src", "images/member_images/" + response.image );

      },
      error: function( error )
      {

         alert( error );

      }

   } );

}
```

and the relevant code in "contents/php_scripts/admin_scripts.php" is as follows:

```
   if( isset( $_POST[ "get_member" ] ) )
   {

      $member_id = $_POST[ "get_member" ];
      $query = "select * from members where id = '$member_id'";

      $result = mysql_query( $query );

      $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

      $type = $row[ "type" ];
      $name = $row[ "name" ];
      $fname = $row[ "fname" ];
      $lname = $row[ "lname" ];
      $email = $row[ "email" ];
      $phone = $row[ "phone" ];
      $website = $row[ "website" ];
      $image = $row[ "image" ];

      $json_arr = array( "type" => $type, "name" => $name, "fname" => $fname, "lname" => $lname, "email" => $email, "phone" => $phone, "website" => $website, "image" => $image );

      echo json_encode( $json_arr );

   }
```

Comment: Try alert(JSON.stringify(error)) as it should display more information about the error in the alert dialog

Comment: I'd guess that there's a PHP error before JSON is echoed. Check your fetch function, you are addressing data as $row['key'], so you should have used mysql_fetch_assoc instead, I believe. 

Change '$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );' to
'$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );'
and see if it works.

Comment: Pay attention: if there is no previous sanitization, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Hi thanks, no PHP error, dry-ran the script without js calling it and it was fine...

Comment: @Jack Duluoz, yes, i got more information... here is what it spit out: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"type\":\"Person\",\"name\":\"\",\"fname\":\"Adriana\",\"lname\":\"Pitea\",\"email\":\"piotr.zywien@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"1234567\",\"website\":\"\",\"image\":null}","status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}

Comment: have you tried removing dataType option and let jQuery guess the format? works with me

Answer (score 24):

I think I know this one...

Try sending your JSON as JSON by using PHP's [header()](http://php.net/header/) function:

```
/**
 * Send as JSON
 */
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

Though you are passing valid JSON, jQuery's $.ajax doesn't think so because it's missing the header.

jQuery used to be fine without the header, but it was changed a few versions back.

**ALSO**

Be sure that your script is returning valid JSON. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Google Chrome's Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) to check the request's response in the console.

**UPDATE**

You will also want to update your code to sanitize the $_POST to avoid sql injection attacks. As well as provide some error catching.

```
if (isset($_POST['get_member'])) {

    $member_id = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["get_member"]);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `id` = '" . $member_id . "';";

    if ($result = mysql_query( $query )) {

       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

       $type = $row['type'];
       $name = $row['name'];
       $fname = $row['fname'];
       $lname = $row['lname'];
       $email = $row['email'];
       $phone = $row['phone'];
       $website = $row['website'];
       $image = $row['image'];

       /* JSON Row */
       $json = array( "type" => $type, "name" => $name, "fname" => $fname, "lname" => $lname, "email" => $email, "phone" => $phone, "website" => $website, "image" => $image );

    } else {

        /* Your Query Failed, use mysql_error to report why */
        $json = array('error' => 'MySQL Query Error');

    }

     /* Send as JSON */
     header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

    /* Return JSON */
    echo json_encode($json);

    /* Stop Execution */
    exit;

}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer above to include a code update. Check to make sure your query is returning results and an error isn't breaking the JSON response.

Comment: Also, try passing the $replace parameter to header: header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

Comment: @Piotr, are you getting the correct JSON response from the server?

Comment: @McHerbie, yes i am... although it seems to get a parse error and I'm not sure how do fix it.

Comment: here is the error btw: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"type\":\"Person\",\"name\":\"\",\"fname\":\"A­driana\",\"lname\":\"Pitea\",\"email\":\"piotr.zywien@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"123­4567\",\"website\":\"\",\"image\":null}","status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}

Comment: @Piotr, are you able to get the response headers for the request? Firebug or Google Developer Tools will provide the details for you.

Comment: The JSON contained in `responseText` looks OK to my Chrome 9 installation.

Comment: yup... still, it screws up... any ideas? i'm desperate by this stage! :(

Comment: @Piotr, paste the server's response headers here to be sure they are set correctly.

Comment: this may be a terrible thing to ask, but how can i do that, since i'm running the website locally on mamp pro.

Comment: @Piotr, What browser are you using? If using Firebug, you can find the information under the 'Net' panel. http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: Ok cool! You can access the Google Chrome Developer Tools by pressing "Control + Shift + I". Once open click on the 'Network' tab and it should show you the web page's network activity. 

On the right, you should see the request made to your script (admin_scripts.php). If you click on the request, it'll load showing you the Content and allowing you to view the Headers as well.

Comment: Hi McHerbie, thanks! Here is the request content: {"type":"Person","name":"","fname":"Piotr","lname":"Zywien","email":"piotr.zywien@gmail.com","phone":"1234567","website":"","image":"ja.JPG"}

Comment: sorry, response headers: Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:199
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 28 Feb 2011 23:59:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=92
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.2

Comment: @McHerbie, do you have any more ideas how to fix it? :)

Comment: @Piotr, did you get a status code of 200? I am running out of ideas... Umm.. You can also try removing the JSON header() from the PHP and then update the $.ajax request to as as plain text ('dataType: "text",') to see if the issue lies in jQuery's JSON parser.

Comment: @McHerbie, yes, checked it - it works fine as dataType: "text"... :S

Comment: @Piotr.... It's obviously failing in the jQuery's JSON parser. Be sure that the JSON is in fact valid (http://www.jsonlint.com/) and also maybe try changing the version of jQuery you are using (I do this some times to see if it's me or the frameworks).

Answer (score 10):

Try using jQuery.parseJSON when you get the data back.

```
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: url,
data: { get_member: id },
success: function(data) { 
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $("input[ name = type ]:eq(" + response.type + " )")
        .attr("checked", "checked");
    $("input[ name = name ]").val( response.name);
    $("input[ name = fname ]").val( response.fname);
    $("input[ name = lname ]").val( response.lname);
    $("input[ name = email ]").val( response.email);
    $("input[ name = phone ]").val( response.phone);
    $("input[ name = website ]").val( response.website);
    $("#admin_member_img")
        .attr("src", "images/member_images/" + response.image);
},
error: function(error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

Comment: success function returns empty data if i set `dataType : 'json'`, else prints complete json element into html like this `[{"id":"1001","full_name":"raju "}]`.

Answer (score 5):

The `$.ajax` `error` function takes three arguments, not one:

```
error: function(xhr, status, thrown)
```

You need to dump the 2nd and 3rd parameters to find your cause, not the first one.

Comment: Hi Alnitak thanks, here is what status and thrown gave out: 'parsererror - jQuery150010872808285057545_1298928988511 was not called' Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to McHerbie's note, try `json_encode( $json_arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );` if you are on PHP 5.3...

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this...  
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#find").click(function(){
        var username  = $("#username").val();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'includes/find.php',
            data: 'username='+username,
            success: function( data ) {
            //in data you result will be available...
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
//further code..
            },

    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
        },
    dataType: 'text'

    });
        });

    });



    </script>

    <form name="Find User" id="userform" class="invoform" method="post" />

    <div id ="userdiv">
      <p>Name (Lastname, firstname):</p>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="inputfield" />
      <input type="button" name="find" id="find" class="passwordsubmit" value="find" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="userinfo"><b>info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  session_start();
include('connection.php');

/* function msg($subjectname,$coursename,$sem)
    {
    return '{"subjectname":'.$subjectname.'"coursename":'.$coursename.'"sem":'.$sem.'}';
    }*/ 
$title_id=$_POST['title_id'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE id='$title_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$qr=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$subject=$qr['subject'];
$course=$qr['course'];
$resultes=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course JOIN subject ON course.id='$course' AND subject.id='$subject'");
$qqr=mysql_fetch_array($resultes);
$subjectname=$qqr['subjectname'];
$coursename=$qqr['coursename'];
$sem=$qqr['sem'];
$json = array("subjectname" => $subjectname, "coursename" => $coursename, "sem" => $sem,);
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode( $json_arr );


 $.ajax({type:"POST",    
                  dataType: "json",    
                   url:'select-title.php',
                   data:$('#studey-form').serialize(),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   beforeSend: function(x) {
        if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
                   success:function(response)
                  {
                    var response=$.parseJSON(response)
                    alert(response.subjectname);
                    $('#course').html("<option>"+response.coursename+"</option>"); 
                    $('#subject').html("<option>"+response.subjectname+"</option>");

                  },
                  error: function( error,x,y)
                  {

                  alert( x,y );

              }
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version (over 1.3.x) you should learn more about the function parseJSON! I experienced the same problem. Use an old version  or change your code

```
success=function(data){
  //something like this
  jQuery.parseJSON(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might help someone. I was stupid enough to put `var_dump('testing');` in the function I was requesting JSON from to be sure the request was actually received. This obviously also echo's as part for the expected `json` response, and with `dataType` set to `json` defined, the request fails.