# AJAX Returns Null in Firefox/IE but Object in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been bashing my head against the computer trying to figure this out. My AJAX call/request returns the correct object in Chrome but in Firefox/IE8 it returns null. I've tried stripping down my function to a simple array with one value/key pair and I still receive the same result. Any suggestions is much appreciated!

Simplified PHP Function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ldap', 'get_ldap_attr');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ldap', 'get_ldap_attr');

function get_ldap_attr() {
  header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
  echo json_encode( array("happy" => "coding") );
  die();
}
```

The jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#empLanId').on('blur', function () {
     var lan = jQuery('#empLanId').val();
     var data = { action:"get_ldap", lan:lan };
     var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php", null); ?>';
       jQuery.ajax({
          url: ajaxurl,
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {     
            console.log(response);
          }
      });
  });

}
```

Comment: The only situation where response would be null is if you're using an older version of jQuery and your json request is returning `""` (empty string)

Comment: My company uses jQuery version 1.7.1

Comment: Yes, in 1.9, an empty string is correctly treated as invalid JSON. the problem you are having is either not client-side, or it's related to the url you are using and/or the data you are sending.

Comment: Then why is it working in Chrome but not in Firefox/IE?

Comment: That's why i suspect it's related to the data you are sending or the url you are using, since that's the only thing you haven't provided.  I'm using deductive reasoning. Since you are getting to the success callback, we know for a fact that the php is returning 200 status code. And, since response is null and you're using 1.7, the only possible reason for that to happen is if your php is returning an empty string. Now we just have to figure out why your php is returning an empty string in IE but not Chrome.

Comment: var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php", null); ?>';

Comment: Maybe Firefox/IE isn't parsing the JSON object correctly?

Comment: Add console.log(jQuery('#empLanId').val()); and press F12 in IE, do same in chrome with it's console. do they match?

Comment: If it wasn't parsing the JSON object, you wouldn't be getting null as your response, instead you would not be getting a console log at all because the error callback would be getting called rather than success.

Comment: Just tried it and they do match...

Comment: and you're definitely getting `null` in the console in IE, not just nothing?

Comment: The JSON object I receive from the PHP callback function is considered valid JSON per http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are actually getting that json object in IE?

Comment: When I fire the PHP function without AJAX I receive the correct JSON object in all three browsers. If that makes sense.

Comment: I get that much, but is that same json object the one that is being returned to IE and Firefox. Inspect it with firebug and the network tab in IE console.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You must send the correct content-type with your JSON response.

```
// Send as JSON
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

Your updated function should look like this:

```
function get_ldap_attr() {
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode( array("happy" => "coding") );
    die();
}
```

See my previous answer here:

[jQuery $.ajax request of dataType json will not retrieve data from PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147522/jquery-ajax-request-of-datatype-json-will-not-retrieve-data-from-php-script/5147597#5147597)

Comment: this is not a requirement(though it is a good idea) as long as the dataType option is correctly set (which it is)

Comment: What is the value of `ajaxurl`?