# JQuery not receiving json data stucture just empyt []

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to make an ajax call and receive json from a php script that will then be processed in the js code.

For some reason when the json is passed to the callback function its an empty array... so `console.log(json)` gives `[]`

However, when I call the php script it gives me valid json as output of `["7494","7495","7565"]` in the browser.

This is the AJAX / JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
       url:'validation_ajax.php',
       data:{
         'jobids': 'yes',
         'projectid': '3062'
      },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
     success: function(d){
                console.log(d);
     },
     error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
                    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                    console.log( "Status: " + status );
                    console.dir( xhr );
     }
  });
```

The PHP is this

```
$projectId = testInput($_GET['project']);
$con = dbConnect();
$sql = "select distinct iJobID from Validation_Samples 
        where iProjectID =   $projectId";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$jobs = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $jobs[] = $row['iJobID'];
    }
    echo json_encode($jobs);

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147522/jquery-ajax-request-of-datatype-json-will-not-retrieve-data-from-php-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET['project']` is empty, should be `$_GET['projectid']` I assume.
Also do `mysqli_close($con)` before the echo.