# AJAX request returns null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following PHP:

```
<?php

 $get_messages = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM messages");

 $messages = array();

 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_messages)){

      $messages[] = array( 'name' => $row['name'], 'message' => $row['message']);
 }

 $json = json_encode($messages);
 echo $json;

?>
```

Which successfully echo the following JSON:

```
     [{"name":"Ernest","message":"hello"},{"name":"Ernest","message":"hello"},{"name":"john","message":"yes"},{"name":"Diana","message":"I know\r\n"},{"name":"fgafg","message":"fgehfegfvg"},{"name":"fgafg","message":"fgehfegfvg"},{"name":"fgafg","message":"fgehfegfvg"},{"name":"gsfvgx","message":"fbhfxvcz"},{"name":"argttrhjyrbsgdzdc","message":"ahjtgfrdcvdfsevb"}]
```

Then I have this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
     url: 'retrieve.php',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (response) {
       alert(response[3]);
     }
   });
});
```

which alerts undefined.

What is the issue here ? Your help will be appreciated.

NOTE: If I change the alert to   `alert(response[3].name);` or `alert(response[3][name]);` the alert window does not even show up to the party

Comment: What about if you just do `alert(response);`

Comment: Or ```console.log(response);``` to more easily examine it in the JavaScript console in browsers.

Comment: What about if you use `header('Content-type: application/json');` at the beginning of your PHP code?

Comment: @Musa `alert(response);` gets me an empty alert

Comment: @MasterOdin `console.log(response);` shows the same behavior

Comment: @gabe adding `header('Content-type: application/json');` is not doing the trick either. I had already tried, and tried again when you suggested.

Comment: I saw your JSON again and I think that the problem comes from escaped charactars `\n` or `\r`. I think this will help you `echo str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $json)`

Comment: @gabe Still not working, I even got rid of that entry in my database. It seems like that was not the problem. Or at least, not the only problem

Comment: That is really strange. The solution given by @Shyju should work. Are you sure that this `url: 'retrieve.php'` is the correct address? This suppose that the `php` file is in the same place where the `ajax` call is. Can you please check that?

Comment: @Franco yes, the url is correct. Both files are in the same folder and I am using MAMP if hat matters.

Comment: Ok, are you using than some framework? Because this is really strange.

Comment: Nope, no framework. I know , it's really weird. I have been browsing for hours but have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: What happens if you remove the dataType from the ```$.ajax``` call and then ```console.log(response);```?

Answer (score 0):

`response` is an array of items with `name` and `message` properties. So you should basically loop through the items and access it.

You need to make sure that your ajax call is hitting the `success` handler. May be add an `error` handler to verify it.

```
success: function (response) {

   $.each(response,function(a,b){
     alert(b.name);
     alert(b.message);
   });       

 },
 error : function(a,b,c){
    alert("error");
    alert(c);
 }
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/gidawu/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample of iterating the array.

Also, If there are any other script error in your page, it won't work. So make sure you don't have any other script error. You can verify it by checking your browser console.

Comment: I tried iterating through it as you suggested but that did not work either. It looks like the JSON object is not even being passed on to my AJAX function

Comment: do a console.log(response) and see what happens.

Comment: i get  empty brackets `[]`

Comment: That means, It is getting an empty array. You need to check your server code to make sure that it is returning a proper array.

Comment: I have checked. I included retrieve.php in an HTML page and it echos a valid JSON data set.The problem is when I try to get JSON through AJAX.

Comment: Take a look at this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147522/jquery-ajax-request-of-datatype-json-will-not-retrieve-data-from-php-script. It might help. Sorry i am not a PHP person :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    message: JSON.stringify(message)
                },
                url: "retrieve.php",
                success: function(message) {
                        alert(message);
                }
            });
```