# Ajax post not passing data to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I'm having trouble with passing data using ajax post to php
Here is my jquery :

```
    $('#kodeobat').on('change',function(){
        var kodeobat = $(this).val();

            if (kodeobat = ""){
            $("#hargaobat").val("");
          } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'kodeobat': kodeobat },
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "getdata.php",
                    success: function(json) {
                        $("#hargaobat").val(json["hargaobat"]);
                    }
                });
          }
        });
```

and here is the php file:

```
$kodeobat = $_POST['kodeobat'];
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT kodeobat, hargaobat FROM Obat WHERE kodeobat='".$kodeobat."'");
$stmt->execute();

while($row=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 if($kodeobat == $row['kodeobat']){
  echo json_encode($row);
 }
}
```

and it results : Notice: Undefined index: kodeobat in .../getdata.php on line 4 which is this line $kodeobat = $_POST['kodeobat'];

Is there something wrong with the code? Thank youuu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#kodeobat').on('change',function(){
    var kodeobat = $(this).val();

        if (kodeobat == ""){
        $("#hargaobat").val("");
      } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'kodeobat': kodeobat },
                dataType: "json",
                url: "getdata.php",
                success: function(json) {
                    $("#hargaobat").val(json["hargaobat"]);
                }
            });
      }
    });
```

Notice if (kodeobat == "")

Comment: OMG how could I miss that one >.<
I though that was something wrong with the ajax :(
Thank you so much Bro! :))

Comment: Believe me even I've missed that a lot of times :)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your JSON as JSON by using PHP's header() function:
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

[look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147522/jquery-ajax-request-of-datatype-json-will-not-retrieve-data-from-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

If you are unaware of what type of value you would get in response here is a try..

```
  $kodeobat = $_POST['kodeobat'];
  if(empty($kodeobat)) {
    echo("Value is empty");
  } else if(is_array($kodeobat)) {
    $i = count($kodeobat);     //If the value is array iterate it
    for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
      echo($kodeobat[$i] . " ");
    }
  } else if(is_object($kodeobat)){
    $json = json_decode($_POST,true);  //if it is a json value decode it
    $kodeobat_new = $json['kodeobat'];
  }
```