# jQuery Ajax with dataType JSON and getJSON issue

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I  am using an ajax function using jQuery $.ajax, on the success this function calling another function that uses getJSON to retrieve data, but when I use dataType: 'JSON' with the $.ajax function the second function is not executed. Is this behaviour is normal or I am doing something wrong.

let me give you the code::
first function:

```
$('#someButton').on('click', function(){

   $.ajax({
                url: uploadURI,
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'JSON', //when I add this line second function stopped working, I need this to do some checks.
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function() {
                    listFilesOnServer();
                }
    })
});
```

second function::

```
function listFilesOnServer () {
        var items = [];

        $.getJSON(uploadURI, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                items.push('<li class="list-group-item">' + element  + '<div class="pull-right"><a href="#" data-file="' + element + '" class="remove-file"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></div></li>');
            });
            $('.list-group').html("").html(items.join(""));
        });
    }
```

For the first function's server side code(PHP) I want to use the json_encode function, but this behaviour stopping me. Is this normal or any workaround for this.

Comment: can you please post PHP code too for first ajax request?

Comment: I am  using this with CI project,function is ::  public function listFiles()
 {
  $this->load->helper('file');
  $files = get_filenames("./assets/uploads");
  echo json_encode($files);
 }

Comment: @vijayP as I said this all working fine Until I use dataType:'JSON' in my first $.ajax function

Comment: may this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147522/jquery-ajax-request-of-datatype-json-will-not-retrieve-data-from-php-script. Try setting the response header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#someButton').on('click', function(){
   $.ajax({
        url: uploadURI,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json', //When you using this, that mean you want the php to return JSON format too
        success: function() { //If the result from PHP can't be parsed, the success function will not be triggered
            listFilesOnServer();
        }, 
        error: function() { //The request completed.. but..
            alert('Returned data has an error!');
            listFilesOnServer(); //Do the second function here..
        }
    })
});
// Make sure you have add this line before echo the json data in PHP script
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Alternative check:

```
//remove -> dataType: 'json'
success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);
    try {
        JSON.parse(data);
    } catch(e){
        alert('Data is not a raw JSON');
        return;
    }

    //The data was a json, continuing to second function
    listFilesOnServer();
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay, you are right I am getting result in to second function getJSON is not a raw JSON data, I dont know why, I am using json_encode function in my php code, result is an array variable($files) like this:: echo json_encode($files); what is wrong with my code, any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Put contentType : 'multipart/form-data', instead of false.
Remove ProcessData (Optional in ajax)
Send Data in JSON format eg:  data : { Form: formData },