# Unable to pass Value from PHP to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the communication between AJAX and PHP. I've already tried all these pieces of code from related questions and answers but nothing worked. This code should recieve a JSON string from a PHP file on the same server and display the values in the HTML area.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(ajaxcall, 1000);
});

function ajaxcall(){
var data = $('#signup_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            window.console.log("Success");
            document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = $('#time').html(data.time);
    },error: function alert(){"error";}
});}
```

When I execute the script in my browser (with debug mode) then nothing happens. I assume this implies a problem with the 'success' method.

Here is a part of my PHP code (for testing):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){
    sleep(1);
    return_json($argv[1]);
}

//return all values for html/javascript
function return_json($a){
    $json = array('time' => $a);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

I hope some of you can help me :)

Comment: Does the ajax call ctually return something? Use firebug or something simular to check hwat your ajax call is returning

Comment: with the 'window.console' method i should be able to see something every second, but nothing is written in the console.

Comment: where you have set up variable from $_GET? $argv is used for cli I think...for ajax use superglobal $_GET

Comment: even if it works, this is likely to output lots of disparate JSON objects or arrays. not sure this will form a valid response on the client. Collect all your data into one place in the PHP and then do one json_encode command on all of it, to form a coherent object/array to output. Secondly, you're not reading the input data in PHP - you need to read the contents of the `$_GET` array (and validate it!!!). Lastly `error: function alert(){"error";}` should be `error: function () { alert("error");}` I think (although it could also take the status code/message as well and log/alert them).

Comment: The $argv is just the input for the PHP script. Thanks for the hint with the error part, this is now working. But it still doesn't get data from my PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the content type to your response header:

```
//this line
header('Content-type: application/json');

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){
    sleep(1);
    return_json($argv[1]);
}

//return all values for html/javascript
function return_json($a){
    $json = array('time' => $a);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Further reading and a more detailed explanation here: j[Query $.ajax request of dataType json will not retrieve data from PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147522/jquery-ajax-request-of-datatype-json-will-not-retrieve-data-from-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

Is the function `ajaxcall()` really being called? Try to add a `console.log` call at its begining, eg

```
function ajaxcall(){
   var data = $('#signup_form').serialize();
   console.log(' form data = %o', data)

   //...
```

There is another possible issue the function `error: function alert(){"error";}` does nothing visible. If your server script is returning an error you will see nothing in this case.

Change it to something like

`error: function(){ alert("error"); }`